# How to improve usability of Ubuntu by providing feedback?

Tags: usability

I have several ideas how to improve the usability of the Ubuntu desktop.

What the next step?

Where should I post my ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. Ubuntu Wiki.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommunityHelpWiki

2. Fridge.

http://fridge.ubuntu.com/

Also you can post your ideas in any blog, site, etc. that allows it.

Comment: I have the feeling, that no one who is able the take influence on the future of ubuntu is listening on the links you provide. I could start developing improvements. But before developing, you want to talk about the direction where to go to.